# Is it possible to run only one specific test in CasperJS?

Tags: casperjs

I need something similar to mocha's `only` method

```
it.only "should test something"
```

For those who doesn't know it means that mocha will launch only this one test among all the tests that will be launched if I wouldn't write `only`

Is it possible to do similar in CasperJS? Now I'm using annoying "comment/uncomment" technique

Comment: What do you call _one test_ ? a file/scenario, a step? an assertion? Do you want to filter some assertions?

Comment: @Fanch I guess it is called scenario. I.e. `casper.test.begin`

Answer (score 0):

You could use an argument option : `casperjs test scriptName.js --only=true`

And in your casperjs file :

```js
if (casper.cli.get("only")){var only=true;}
else {var only=false;}
```

And then before your wanted assertion :

```js
if (!only){ test.assertExists(....);}
else {"should test something"}
```

You can do the reverse in a similar way.

**EDIT :**

If it's a scenario you could use the casperjs `setUp()` function and call another function() which filters the scenarios, using a command option and `casper.test.done()`, like that :

```js
var setLevel = function(level){
    if(casper.cli.get("mode") !== level){
        casper.test.done();
    }
};


casper.test.begin('\n***** Scenario : *****',{
setUp: function(test) {
    setLevel("only");
},

test: function(test){
    "use strict";
    casper.start()
    .run(function() {
            this.test.comment('--- Done ---\n');
            test.done();
    });
}
});
```

So if you call it with `casperjs test path/to/folder --mode="only"`, it will instantly close every scenario where level isn't set to **only**. It will output opening logs though, if you don't want to see them, use the [casper.test.setUp()](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/tester.html#setup) method before `casper.test.begin()`. Yes it's strange to finish test before calling begin() but if I remember well it works.

It's also an ugly hack, but for me it's a solution. The problem is : it's necessary to use `setUp()` and `setLevel()` in every files. There isn't a native option to do it anyway.

Comment: That's ugly hack, not a solution

Answer (score 0):

Create your own two functions that wrap `casper.test.begin` and use them. You will need a third function that actually schedules the tests (for monkey patched version see below the jump):

```js
var testcase = (function(casper){
    var scenarios = [],
        onlySet = false;
    return {
        it: function(){
            if (!onlySet) {
                scenarios.push(arguments);
            }
        },
        itOnly: function(){
            onlySet = true;
            scenarios = [arguments];
        },
        build: function(){
            scenarios.forEach(function(scenario){
                casper.test.begin.apply(casper.test, scenario);
            });
        }
    };
})(casper);
```

You can then write your scenarios in this way:

```js
testcase.it("something", function suite(test){
    test.assert(true);
});

testcase.itOnly("something2", function suite(test){
    test.assert(true);
});

testcase.it("something3", function suite(test){
    test.assert(true);
});

testcase.build();
```

The output will be:

```
# something2
PASS Subject is strictly true
```

---

You can of course monkey patch the `casper.test` instance with your functions:

```js
(function(casper){
    // IIFE to avoid leaking scenarios
    var scenarios = [],
        onlySet = false,
        oldBegin = casper.test.begin;
    casper.test.begin = function(){
        if (!onlySet) {
            scenarios.push(arguments);
        }
    };
    casper.test.beginOnly = function(){
        onlySet = true;
        scenarios = [arguments];
    };
    casper.test.build = function(){
        scenarios.forEach(function(scenario){
            oldBegin.apply(casper.test, scenario);
        });
    };
})(casper);

casper.test.begin("something", function suite(test){
    test.assert(true);
});

casper.test.beginOnly("something2", function suite(test){
    test.assert(true);
});

casper.test.begin("something3", function suite(test){
    test.assert(true);
});

casper.test.build();
```